Locate Duplicate Part Numbers and Adjust Cell Quantity Sum Accordingly
I pull data from Access into an Excel Table. The data is sorted by date, and then customer name.
I would like to search for duplicate Part Numbers and subtract the 'Available Quantity' accordingly.
The top table shows what I'm currently experiencing and the bottom table is what I'm after.
The top table creates a false inventory level because some units shown as available aren't available as they are slotted for an earlier date.


It's going to be up to your VBA code to track the "current quantity".  Access can't do that.  If you haven't seen the part number before, then set current quantity for that part to available minus required.  If you HAVE seen it before, then use your stored value, not the one in the record.

Thank you for your response. I'm wanting to track it in VBA. The data is being pulled from a report in Access but everything else is entered into a table and displayed in Excel. I'm not really sure what code to use to accomplish what you've described.

Please share the details of the code you tried and describe the issue you are encountering.

So, is your VBA code doing the import?  You will need to loop over the records one by one.

I don't have much knowledge in VBA and am just starting to learn. I basically tried creating a column using cell formulas with COUNTIF and other functions with no success.

No, VBA is not doing the import - it is manually imported into Excel. Once the data is pulled into an Excel table (manually), I would like to be able to have VBA loop each line to determine if it is duplicated or not and if so, decrement the available quantity accordingly in the following record.

Right.  That's exactly what you need, a loop to process each row.  I see that @taller has posted code that does exactly this.

Use Dict object to track availble quantity for each part.
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, sKey As String
    Dim arrData
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set rngData = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arrData = rngData.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        sKey = arrData(i, 1)
        If objDic.exists(sKey) Then
            arrData(i, 3) = objDic(sKey)
            objDic(sKey) = objDic(sKey) - arrData(i, 2)
        Else
            objDic(sKey) = arrData(i, 3) - arrData(i, 2)
        End If
    Next i
    rngData.Value = arrData
End Sub

Microsoft documentation:

Dictionary object


Range.CurrentRegion property (Excel)



The formula solution can be like this:

E2 and fill down=XLOOKUP(A2;$A$2:$A$6;$C$2:$C$6)-SUM(($A$2:$A2=A2)*$B$2:$B2)+B2


Formula version works perfectly as well! Thank you!
